# Oracle sequence desynchronisation after expdp / impdp

Tags: oracle

I have 2 databases PROD and TEST running on Oracle 19.
From time to time I refresh TEST with a copy of PROD made using expdp. The copy is done while the PROD db is running.
The refreshed TEST schema is dropped and then created again before impdp.
After the refresh of TEST is done, some sequences are not up to date : when our application does a seq.nextval it gets a value already used in a table and so the INSERT using that value fails.

Is there a parameter to add to the expdp parameter file to get the up to date value of the sequence to be exported ? Or could the problem be caused by something else ?

Comment: "TEST schema is dropped and then created again before impdp" - if you let impdp create the schema objects, or at least the sequences, instead of pre-creating them then you wouldn't have this issue, would you?

Comment: Yes, the impdp creates all the schema objects. But before running impdp, the schema / user is created manually and empty, without any object in it.

Comment: OK, then are you doing a consistent export, with [flashback_time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle-data-pump-export-utility.html#GUID-CB8386E5-CA76-4D4A-884E-F97BFC58B230) (or flashback_scn)?

Answer (score 1):

> The copy is done while the PROD db is running.

It sounds like you are ending up with an inconsistent export because there is activity going on while it is performed, including things that are incrementing sequences after their state has been captured. When a table that used the higher sequence value is exported later it has a value ahead of the sequence export.

You can use the [`FLASHBACK_TIME` parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle-data-pump-export-utility.html#GUID-CB8386E5-CA76-4D4A-884E-F97BFC58B230) (or `FLASHBACK_SCN`) to make it consistent, as long as you have enough undo/retention configured:

> The Data Pump Export command-line utility FLASHBACK_TIME parameter finds the SCN that most closely matches the specified time. This SCN is used to enable the Flashback utility. The export operation is performed with data that is consistent up to this SCN.

You can specify a particular time, but from your description you can probably just use:

```
FLASHBACK_TIME=systimestamp
```

You can also adjust all your sequences to the highest actual value after import, but that's a bit more work.